# MouseOver event is not triggered in svg - clippath region in Chrome?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I use d3 to create a line chart with circle points... Just tried to figure out this http://bl.ocks.org/bobmonteverde/2070123 ...In Chrome the mouseover and mouseout events are not triggered in some circle points  whereas it works fine in firefox and safari...

```
  var pointPaths = wrap.select('.point-paths').selectAll('path')
      .data(voronoi);
  pointPaths.enter().append('path')
      .attr('class', function(d,i) { return 'path-' + i; })
  pointPaths.exit().remove();
  pointPaths
      .attr('clip-path', function(d) { return 'url(#clip-' + id + '-' + d.series + '-' + d.point + ')'; })

      .attr('d', function(d) { return 'M' + d.data.join(',') + 'Z'; })
      .on('mouseenter', function(d,i) { 
        console.log("MouseOver:---",d, "i ==== ",i);
        wrap.select('.line-' + d.series + ' .point-' + d.point)
          .classed('hover', true);
      })
      .on('mouseleave', function(d) {
       // console.log("mouseOut:---",d);
        wrap.select('.line-' + d.series + ' .point-' + d.point)
          .classed('hover', false);
       });
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vVEDG/1/

Why the mouseover events are not fired at x-points 13,15,17,19 ???

Any Suggestions ???

I using Chrome 26.0.1410.65

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I could tell by playing around with your jsFiddle, I think the issue has to do with the coordinates of the pointPaths.  They have coordinates like negative and positive 1000000.  I've had issues before with chrome where giving it huge numbers like that as coordinates for some element will throw things off.  I tried forcing it to use 1000 and -1000 for those coordinates, and the mouseover events worked on some of the bad pointPaths.  I didn't post the fiddle because it also messed up a lot of other stuff, I'll let you figure out how to modify your code to change these coordinates to something more reasonable, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Ryan Lynch... How can i restrict to those coordinates ???

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not really familiar enough with what you are trying to do to help you out with that.  Did you write this yourself?  Or did you get bits from an example somewhere?

Comment: And by what you are trying to do I mean the Voronoi tessellation bit.

Comment: Hey it worked for me man... Restricting the voronoi points fixed my issue.... Thanks @Ryan Lynch

Comment: Sure thing.  If it worked then go ahead and accept the answer so people know when they look at this question in the future.